# ubuntu 12.04 cant boot with kernel 3.2.0-49 and 3.2.0-51

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

I am now using ubuntu12.04 with kernel 3.2.0-48.
Where can i find some logs which will help me to find the reason?
sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

The following link may be of help and shows how to check boot errors:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-view-boot-log/